# sql/php to grab the minimum & maximum from multiple table entries

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, parent-child, children

I hope the below makes sense...

I'm grabbing all of the children records using the following (another script does the *getChildRecords*):

```
<?php $children = $this->item->getChildRecords(); ?>
```

I am then doing a foreach to grab all of the children house ID's:

```
<?php
foreach ( $children as $i => $id )
  {
    $house = JTable::getInstance('house', 'MyTable');
    $house->load($id);
?>
```

Then I am pulling back the number of rooms for each child house entry:

```
<div><?php $house->rooms; ?></div>
```

And finishing off my foreach:

```
<?php } ?>
```

The children table may contain the following room entries:

**ID** - 22
**Rooms** - 1 |
**ID** - 22
**Rooms** - 5 |
**ID** - 22
**Rooms** - 2 |
**ID** - 22
**Rooms** - 3

***Question:***

What I want to show is the Min to Max number of rooms from all of the child entries.

i.e. 1-5

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is?

Comment: If I just use <?php $house->rooms; ?> - I would get 1523 (the rooms) - what I want is the min/max, i.e. 1-5

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need the single children entries on that page? Or is it an overview?
If you don't need the single entries you could create a function like

```
public function getMinAndMaxRooms() {
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    $result mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, MIN(rooms), MAX(rooms) FROM rooms GROUP BY id");
    if ($result !== false) {
        return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);
    }
    return array();
}
```

And in your template cycle through it:

```
<?php foreach ($this->item->getChildRecords() as $child) : ?>
<?php echo $child[0) . ': ' . $child[1] . '-' - $child[2] ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```